# Remove duplicates making sure of NA values R

Tags: r, duplicates, na, missing-data

My data set(df) looks like,

```
   ID    Name    Rating    Score  Ranking
   1     abc       3        NA      NA
   1     abc       3        12      13
   2     bcd       4        NA      NA
   2     bcd       4        19      20
```

I'm trying to remove duplicates which using

```
   df <- df[!duplicated(df[1:2]),]
```

which gives,

```
   ID    Name    Rating    Score  Ranking
   1     abc       3        NA      NA
   2     bcd       4        NA      NA
```

but I'm trying to get,

```
   ID    Name    Rating    Score  Ranking
   1     abc       3        12      13
   2     bcd       4        19      20
```

How do I avoid rows containing NA's when removing duplicates at the same time, some help would be great, thanks.

Comment: did you try `complete.cases()`? You can first filter it via `complete.cases()` and then remove duplicates

Comment: You can also use `order`. NAs will move to the bottom of the pile: `df <- df[with(df, order(ID, Score, Ranking)),]; df <- df[!duplicated(df[1:2]),]`.

Answer (score 1):

First, push the NAs to last with `na.last = T`

```
df<-df[with(df, order(ID, Name, Score, Ranking),na.last = T),]
```

then do the removing of duplicated ones with `fromLast = FALSE` argument:

```
df <- df[!duplicated(df[1:2],fromLast = FALSE),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr

`df <- df %>%  filter(!duplicated(.[,1:2], fromLast = T))`

Answer (score 0):

You could just filter out the observations you don't want with which() and then use the unique() function:

```
a<-unique(c(which(df[,'Score']!="NA"), which(df[,'Ranking']!="NA")))

df2<-unique(df[a,])

> df2
  ID Name Rating Score Ranking
2  1  abc      3    12      13
4  2  bcd      4    19      20
```